# Can I use `Y ~ X + X:Z` when `Z` does not follow a linear relationship with `Y`?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, interaction, aic, biostatistics

### General case

I want to model the relationship between `Y` and `X`, but I am also interested in knowing if this relationship changes depending on `Z` (I am not interested in if `Z` has a linear relationship with `Y`). That is, I am interested in the interaction between `X` and `Z`. `Y` and `X` are continuous variables, and `Z` is a discrete variable, taking integer positive values from 1.

Assuming that my data accomplish all linear model assumptions, does it take sense to compare next models with `AIC` to answer the question "Does it `Z` affects to the linear relationship between `Y` and `X`?":

```
mod1 <- nlme::lme(Y ~ X, random= ~ 1|ID, data = data,method="ML")
mod2 <- nlme::lme(Y ~ X + X:Z, random= ~ 1|ID, data = data,method="ML")

AIC(mod1,mod2)
```

My doubt comes because `Z` might not follow a linear relationship with `Y`, and I don't know if this is a problem. Do I need that `Z` has a linear relationship with `Y` to consider the interaction between `X` and `Z`? As I said, my major interest is to know if `Z` affects the relationship between `X` and `Y`. Regardless of this, should I include a third model like this "Y ~ X*Z" to check that `Z` does not follow a linear relationship with `Y`? Or I just can't look at the interaction between `X` and `Z` if `Z` does not follow a linear relationship with `Y`?

I would appreciate any advice with that.

### Let's go to my specific case

The reason is quite "technical" and I did not want to disturb the focus. I tagged 10 individuals of an animal species with a device (`dev.X`) that records their activity for 1 minute every 5 minutes. Ok? So I have 1 activity value of my animal every 5 minutes. Then, I created fixed time intervals of 1 hour in which I calculated the average activity of my animal using these values. On the other hand, another type of device (`dev.Y`) was placed also in these same individuals. This second device measure activity but at continuous (not every certain time intervals).

I want to know how well the `dev.X` estimates activity of `dev.Y`. Then, what I did was to calculate an activity value for the same one-hour time intervals than with `dev.X` for `dev.Y`. And then, I want to know how well `dev.X` can predict activity of `dev.Y` considering than `dev.X` only record activity 1 minute every 5 minutes. Is it understood? This would be `Act.dev.Y ~ Act.dev.X + (1|ID)`, and then I calculate R² using an appropriate method for a linear-mixed model.

A complication of this is next: `dev.X` sends data by Satelite while data from `dev.Y` is downloaded re-catching the animals. What does it mean? Depending on my animals' behaviour, sometimes I get less than 1 activity record every 5 minutes because my animal hides within rocks. So, I have an extra covariate in which I indicate the number of activity records (`record.num`) I have per hour. Sometimes I can have 12 records and other times I can have 1. Then, my goal is to know if `dev.X` gives good activity estimates of `dev.Y` and if the number of records have an effect on that. Right?

That is, are my estimates better when I have 12 records for `dev.X` than when I only have 1. My hypothesis is that the higher the number of records, the better the activity estimation done of `dev.Y` (there is more part of the time with activity sampled with `dev.X`). So, my interest regarding record.number is to know if it helps to improve the linear relationship between `dev.Y` and `dev.X`, and I am not really interested in knowing if the number of records is related with `dev.Y`. I though on this like an option:

```
mod1 <- nlme::lme(dev.Y ~ dev.X, random= ~ 1|ID, data = data,method="ML")
mod2 <- nlme::lme(dev.Y ~ dev.X + dev.X:record.number, random= ~ 1|ID, data = data,method="ML")

AIC(mod1,mod2)

r.squaredGLMM(mod1)
r.squaredGLMM(mod2) # To check if the consideration of the number of records increases my prediction performance.
```

Can I do this?

Comment: That is an unusual model, since one would usually also include the direct affect of `Z` when it is used in an interaction. So please explain why not! Also, please give some practical context for the model, such question are almost impossible to answer (good!) in the abstract. And, [look through some of the many posts on interactions and nonlinearity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=nonlinear+interaction++answers%3A1)]

Comment: The reason is quite "technical" and I did not want to disturb the focus. I tagged 10 individuals of an animal species with a device (`dev.X`) that records their activity for 1 minute every 5 minutes. Ok? So I have 1 activity value of my animal every 5 minutes. Then, I created fixed time intervals of 1 hour in which I calculated the average activity of my animal using these values. On the other hand, another type of device (`dev.Y`) was placed also in these same individuals. This second device measure activity but at continuous (not every certain time intervals).

Comment: I want to know how well the `dev.X` estimates activity of `dev.Y`. Then, what I did was to calculate an activity value for the same one-hour time intervals than with `dev.X` for `dev.Y`. And then, I want to know how well `dev.X` can predict activity of `dev.Y` considering than `dev.X` only record activity 1 minute every 5 minutes. Is it understood? This would be `Act.dev.Y ~ Act.dev.X + (1|ID)`, and then I calculate R² using an appropriate method for a linear-mixed model.

Comment: A complication of this is next: `dev.X` sends data by Satelite while data from `dev.Y` is downloaded re-catching the animals. What does it mean? Depending on my animals' behaviour, sometimes I get less than 1 activity record every 5 minutes because my animal hides within rocks. So, I have an extra covariate in which I indicate the number of activity records (`record.num`) I have per hour. Sometimes I can have 12 records and other times I can have 1. Then, my goal is to know if `dev.X` gives good activity estimates of `dev.Y` and if the number of records have an effect on that. Right?

Comment: That is, are my estimates better when I have 12 records for `dev.X` than when I only have 1. My hypothesis is that the higher the number of records, the better the activity estimation done of `dev.Y` (there is more part of the time with activity sampled with `dev.X`). So, my interest regarding `record.number` is to know if it helps to improve the linear relationship between `dev.Y` and `dev.X`, and I am not really interested in knowing if the number of records is related with `dev.Y`.